# How can I develop a rule editor for my users with NRule at the back end?

Tags: c#, rule-engine, business-rules, rete, nrules

I've gone through how to guide of **NRule**. However, I am not clear on how can I provide a user interface where one can define their rules and later execute them on some model.
For example: I have a web application where authorized users drafts a contract between two parties. I would like to add another page to this web site with the ability for my users to draft rules and group them under policies. Later apply any policy on the contract model.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: @Sergiy Nikolayev Could you answer this?

Comment: Tagging somebody who has not participated in the question yet doesn't notify them, they have to see this on their own and respond first.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out when I read the help i.e. previous commenter ...

Answer (score 1):

In NRules, "[rules are authored in C# using internal DSL](https://github.com/NRules/NRules)". Therefore, you would need to write component using some thing like compiled expressions to convert text based files to rules in DSL.

If you are interested in component in .NET with a UI for rules generation out of the box, you would could try Workflow Foundation. Or you could also use Drools using its REST services which converts text to rules (without DSL) which has a UI (Drools Guvnor) but not .NET.

Comment: Is there any example for .NET?